# One detail in Zariski Lemma proof

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Zariski's Lemma states that

"Let $A$ be a finitely generated  algebra over a field $k$. If $A$ is a field then $[A:k ]<\infty$."

Anyway, there's one detail in the proof I cannot understand, let's say we have $d\in k[x_1]=B$ and we have $B[1/d]$ is a field, then they claim that $d\in Q$ for all $Q\in Max B$. Why is it? THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can google it with the term Goldman domain, I guess.

But here is a simple argument:

If $d \notin Q$ for some maximal ideal, then $B[\frac{1}{d}] \subset B_Q \subsetneq \operatorname{Frac}(B)$, which is a contradiction, because $B[\frac{1}{d}]=\operatorname{Frac}(B)$ by assumption.